# Publishing to AWS IoT Core Topic from AWS Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, publish

I would like to publish to an AWS IoT Core Topic from AWS Services. It is easy to subscribe to a topic using the rules engine and selecting the respective service, e.g. SNS under the "actions"-section. But I cannot find a solution of going the other way, i.e. sending a message via SNS and then publish that to a topic.

Please also see the appended chart for clarification:

[image: Chart: AWS IoT Core Architecture highlighting the problem]

This is a really hard one for me; nowhere in the AWS description, the forum or anywhere else I could find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I now at least figured out a way to send messages from an EC2 Instance: Register it as a "Thing", download and install the provided "connect_device_package" and then use the any of the APIs.

Comment: Can you please share how to use the device package to publish to AWS IoT. I am having the custom endpoint of the thing, but still not succeeded to find a way to publish to AWS IoT through my app using C#

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to late for this question, but this is how I publish back in the broker from the system. Using nodeJS. You can do it inside a lambda or using an Ec2 instance with a nodeJS app. The follow is an example of part of a lambda code.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const iotdata = new AWS.IotData({endpoint: xxxxxxxxxx})

const publishMqtt = (params) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  iotdata.publish(params, (err, res) => resolve(res)))


module.exports.publishMQTT = async event => {

...
    var params = {
        topic: 'topicTest/1',
        payload: '{"aaa":"bbb"}',
        qos: '0'
    };

    await publishMqtt(params)
...
}
```

Trigger the lambda and just check in the broker if the topic `topicTest/1` was published.